# AWS CLI S3 Access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I am trying to access S3 Bucket using AWS CLI. I have installed and configured AWS CLI referring to [AmazonAWSCLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html). So, when I try to list using `$aws s3 ls s3://xyz/` I am getting the following error:

```
Not supported proxy scheme asusproxy
```

I tried to setup proxy using

```
export HTTP_PROXY=http://username:password@a.b.c.d:n
```

But, still getting the same error. What might be the issue?

Note:-

> The same setup works on an amazon ec2 machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to access AWS through proxy servers, you should configure the HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY environment variables with the IP addresses for your proxy servers.

try:

```
export HTTP_PROXY=http://username:password@a.b.c.d:n
export HTTPS_PROXY=http://username:password@a.b.c.d:n
```

the setup works on your ec2 instance because there is no proxy server.

Comment: Yeah, I know that and I have  mentioned in my question itself that I have setup the proxy using the export commands but, still it gave me the same response."Not supported proxy scheme asusproxy"

Comment: HTTPS_PROXY not only HTTP_PROXY

Comment: it worked! BTW why do you have http in URL for a proxy which is for https?